# Registration is broken after switch to HTTPS

Tags: security, cookie, ssl, https, registration

We switched our shop from HTTP to SSL / HTTPS.
After that, the user registration is broken.
When you type in your data and click at "register", you are re-directed to the registration page without doing anything..

Security settings:

- secure_base_url = https://www.musikhaus-zoelch.de/
- unsecure_base_url = https://www.musikhaus-zoelch.de/
- SSL offloading = SSL_OFFLOADED
- use secure URL in shop / backend = true

Cookie:

- cookie lifetime = 3600
- cookie path = /
- cookie domain = .musikhaus-zoelch.de
- use only http = false
- restrict cookie mode = false

Shop: https://www.musikhaus-zoelch.de

Registration: https://www.musikhaus-zoelch.de/customer/account/create/

Magento Version 1.9.3.6

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you have `form_keys` enabled throughout your checkout and login pages but don't have one output on the customer registration form.

You need to amend your custom registration form to include the `form_key` before the closing tag of the form:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Template file should is:

```
app/design/frontend/<your_theme>/<your_package>/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Comment: YES! it works now, I think it was not a problem with the HTTPS switch... maybe the bug was there since weeks... thanks!